# Two files upload is not working in same form in Magento product page

Tags: magento2, php, file-upload, upload, magento2.4.2

I have a default Magento 2.4.2.installed on my server. I have a page where there are 2 input types of file upload which is not working together. When I remove one input file type then it is working properly but when i add one more then I am not able to move forward. 
The error log is also empty. Please help me in finding the issue.
Please see the attachment.

[image]

Comment: Please share the backend code also, I have a doubt you can check, your id should be unique and `name` should also be unique, so you need to check this at backend coding side.. or try using inspect element to see the value of id and name. Then also check console.log to find the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your input type files in your browser inspect, your id should be unique and name should also be unique, so you need to check this at backend coding side.. or try using inspect element to see the value of id and name. Then also check console.log to find the error. 
For example
**Unique Name**

```
<input type="file" name="vibhore">
<input type="file" name="vibhore">
<!-- here it will give error as name must be unique inside form -->
```

**Unique Id**

```
<input type="file" id="vibh" name="vibhore">
<input type="file" id="vibh" name="vibhore2">
<!-- here it will give error as Id must be unique from javascript point of view -->
```

Thanks,
Vibhore